# How to adjust ID column after deleting a records from HTML table?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, html-table

On my index.php page I have HTML table which shows data (authors and their books) from two different database tables (author and book). First column in the HTML table is ID from the Book table.

The problem is, when I delete a book from index.php page (using delete button inside HTML table), the ID column doesn't "fill" the gap which shows up after deleting a record.

For example, if I have 5 rows in HTML table with ID's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and if I delete third row, the ID column would show up 1, 2, 4, 5; So, I would like the column to "adjust itself" to the new situation and go 1, 2, 3, 4 (because there are no more five books in the table).

Any ideas how to do it?

Here's the code:

```
// Loading all authors

$Authors = array();
$result = mysqli_query ($db, "select * from Author");
if (!$result)
    die (mysqli_error ($db));
while ($Author = mysqli_fetch_object ($result))
    $Authors[$Author->ID] = $Author;

// Loading all books

$result = mysqli_query ($db, "select * from Book");
if (!$result)
    die (mysqli_error ($db));

// Listing all the data

while ($Book = mysqli_fetch_object ($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> {$Book->ID} </td>";
    echo "<td> {$Authors[$Book->Author_ID]->Name} </td>";
    echo "<td> {$Book->Title} </td>";
    echo "<td> {$Book->Publisher} </td>";
    echo "<td> {$Book->Year} </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

- I am using MySQL server 5.5.34 (MySQL community server GPL)
- One author may have written more then one book
- Author_ID is foreign key in Book table

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't display the IDs at all. Database IDs are not meant to be tampered with.

You might use CSS to not have to bother with the numbers at all. Check this out:

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RyGX/

Comment: The nice Mr. David Thomas provided a JS-Solution, too. CSS is by far more elegant, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RyGX/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion. I don't say this is the best solution. Just consider.

You execute your delete query.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = 3;
```

Once deleted you make a select query request with PHP and get the data set to an array.

```
SELECT id, Name from table_name ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Then make a UPDATE execution using a loop.

```
$id = 1;
foreach($dataset as $item)
{
// Your update query
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET ID=$id where Name='" . $item['Name'] . "'";
$id++;
}
```

Before you insert next query you have to get the max value of id and set +1 value as the id of the insert query. This is just an idea. Not the complete code.

Answer (score -1):

don't post the IDs. Instead use a variable that counts the columns to be displayed then use for loop to print the variable.